# Wordpress Installing Theme failed

Tags: wordpress

Here is my error.

Download failed. Could not open handle for fopen() to http://wordpress.org/themes/download/pinboard.1.1.0.zip

Im new to WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following two things to fix this:

First, add this to your wp-config.php file:

```
define(‘WP_TEMP_DIR’,ABSPATH.’wp-content/uploads/’);
```

and give write permission to the upload folder. 
Make sure that ‘wp-include‘ and ‘wp-content‘ directory set to 755 permission. also If you are hosting  WordPress blog on IIS you should make directory writable

else

Try to do it manually... Download the zip file from the url and install the file by upload theme option